# Spring transaction writer and reader in 1 transaction. how to route to reader datasource for all select query?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions

I am using jdbc:mysql:replication
For Example my connection info

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql:replication://masterDB:3306,readerCluster:3306
```

where spring @transaction with readOnly=true will route to reader DB

I have a transaction for example

```
    @Override
    @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    public BankGroup save(BankGroup bankGroup) {
        BankGroup bankGroup= bankGroupRepo.save(bankGroup);
        List<MerchantBankConfig> merchantBankConfigList =merchantBankConfig.findAll();

        // some business logic...

        // end 
        return bankGroup;
    }
```

```
@Override
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public List<MerchantBankConfig> findAll() {
    return merchantBankRepo.findAll();
}
```

in save() method , first it will open a connection in masterDB since readyOnly=false.
after perform bankGroupRepo.save(bankGroup) save method. there is a findAll() method which I hope it route to reader DB.

Understand that the findAll() is using default Propagation.REQUIRED so it will using same transaction.
Is there any other way that can route all select statement to readerDB with best optimize way?

Current I can use Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW to route to reader DB. is there any better way?

```
    @Override
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW , readOnly = true)
    public List<MerchantBankConfig> findAll() {
        return merchantBankRepo.findAll();
    }
```

What i have tried:

1. AOP spring data repositry and use DBContextHolder to set to readerDB by implement AbstractRoutingDataSource

```
public class MasterSlaveRoutingDataSource extends AbstractRoutingDataSource {
    @Override
    protected Object determineCurrentLookupKey() {
        return DatabaseContextHolder.getEnvironment();
    }
}
```

```
@Aspect
@Component
@Order(0)
public class TransactionReadonlyAspect {

    @Around("@annotation(transactional)")
    public Object proceed(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint, org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional transactional) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("Aspect executed db connection = " +transactional.readOnly());
        try {
            if (transactional.readOnly()) {
                DatabaseContextHolder.set(DatabaseEnvironment.READ);
            }
            return proceedingJoinPoint.proceed();
        } finally {
            DatabaseContextHolder.reset();
        }
    }

}
```

This is not working as where is AOP is happened before @transactional is opened in service layer. Even I set the connection to reader, it will no reopen a DB connection since the connection is opened.

Expected:
Best optimize way for all select statement will route to reader DB in this kind of scenario as we have alot of this kind of select query in our project.

Comment: that is bit unclear, how are you going to get fresh data from synchronous replica if you not yet committed writing transaction? IMO, you need to refactor business code.

Comment: Sorry the about demo might have some confusion cause it selecting back bankUserGroup after save. What if i want to select for any table for example some config that. is there a way to route to reader DB in this scenario?

I will edit the demo for avoid confuse.

Comment: As far as I'm aware the only way to implement this is to use 2 datasources and configure the repository classes to use one or the other, this baeldung article describes the basics of it https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-multiple-databases

Comment: that actually changed nothing. Take a look: if at some moment we decided to start reading from replica we need to acquire corresponding connection (you have two servers, two server - two connections), moreover, we need to keep writing connection open in order to be able to issue `commit` somewhen in the near future. `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW , readOnly = true)` (`@Async` is another option) is doing exactly the same, in any case you need to acquire two connections (regardless what JDBC driver is doing under the hood), that is not possible to optimize that.

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov ok thank for the infos , i think there is no way to optimize too.